# Problem with date recognition in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'll explain my problem with an example:

I have three tables: one of dates, another of employees and another of departments.
There are two relationships:

- dim_date[date_id] -> dim_employee[start_date_id]).
- dim_department[department_id -> dim_employee[current_department_id]

**dim_employee**

| name | current_department_id | start_date_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 | 1 | 20210701 |
| Employee 2 | 2 | 20210701 |
| Employee 3 | 2 | 20210901 |
| Employee 4 | 1 | 20220201 |
| Employee 5 | 2 | 20220201 |

**dim_department**

| department | department_id |
| --- | --- |
| Purchase department | 1 |
| Sales department | 2 |

**I want to count how many employees each department had, for example, in February 2022 (using a slicer).**. I've tried this:

```
num_employees_purchase_department = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(dim_employee[employee_id]),
    dim_employee[current_department_id]=1
)
```

However, since the relation is made through start_date_id, I only get the new hires of each department (one for the sales department and one for the purchase department) and not the total number of hired personnel.

**The result that I'm looking for**:

- Employees in Purchase Department: 2
- Employees in Sales department: 3

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just examining the logic of your data and DAX, with no `employee_end_date` you are assuming that any employee hired is still working.  That being the case, you can probably just remove the test  `start_date_id>=20220201,`.

Comment: Exactly. If you want a "picture" of the end of February, you cannot use an interval, you should use one date to take the picture.

Comment: In my original data there is an end_date_id, but for simplicity I didn't write it. Regarding the start_date_id, if I remove it from my DAX expression, how do I calculate the data up to February 2022? Putting a "slicer" would have the same problem.

Comment: Omitting the end date made your logic opaque. If you have an end date then your comparison should be something like `end date after the first day in February` and `start date before the last day in February`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make *dim_date - dim_employee* relationship inactive (in *Data model* view) and add an extra condition into your measure:

```
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(dim_employee[name]),
    dim_employee[start_date_id] <= MAX(dim_date[date_id])
)
```

Don`t forget to use **USERELATIONSHIP()** inside your other measures where active *dim_date - dim_employee* relationship is necessary.